# Step response for different definitions of step function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

I was thinking about the solution of the known problem of determining the step response for the concentration leaving a CSTR tank. The differential equation is:

$\frac{dC}{dt}=\frac{C_{0}-C}{\tau}-kC$

Where $C_0$ is a step input and $C(0)=0$.

$C_0=1$, $t>0$

$C_0=0$, $t<=0$

The solution is as follows:

$C=\frac{C_0}{1+k\tau}(1-exp(-t(1+k\tau)/\tau))$

Now for the derivative we have (I was motivated by the fact that for reactors operating in series, you can combine the first-order equations into higher-order equations that are uncoupled, which requires to know the values of some derivatives of the reactor concentration to use as initial conditions for the uncoupled equation):

$\frac{dC}{dt}=\frac{C_0}{\tau}exp(-t(1+k\tau)/\tau)$

If I evaluate for the limit as $t\rightarrow0+$ I get:

$\frac{dC}{dt}=\frac{C_0}{\tau}$

Which is consistent with which I obtain looking at the right hand side of the differential equation, on the other hand if I evaluate directly for $t=0$, I still have

$\frac{dC}{dt}=\frac{C_0}{\tau}$

for the derivative of the solution, but from the r.h.s. I have:

$\frac{dC}{dt}=0$

because $C=0$ and the step function is defined as zero for $t=0$. I can solve the problem by redefining the step function as:

$C_0=1$, $t>=0$

$C_0=0$, $t<0$

But this sounds to me too artificial, so here is my question: ¿There exist a difference in the solutions depending on how the step function is defined?, It seems to me that the discrepancy in the first case can be originated in trying to analyze an interval that contains a discotinuity, (limiting myself to $t\rightarrow0+$ avoids crossing the discontinuity), but it also sounds to me a little artificial, and can exits situations in which is not possible to "avoid" discontinuities.